# How to check and install Visual Studio 2013 using WiX installer

Tags: wix

In WiX installer, I want to check whether Visual Studio 2013 redistributable package is installed - if not then, then install it.

Can anyone please show me how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: actually, i do have already created installer. but dont know what to write for Visuatl studio 2013 package check and install. so, stuck here.. not tried any thing.

Comment: Then maybe a google search and actually trying it are the best first steps.